# using size for font icon list symbol?

Tags: latex

I'm using these two packages

```
\usepackage{graphicx,pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,pifont}
\let\oldding\ding% Store old \ding in \oldding
\renewcommand{\ding}[2][1]{\scalebox{#1}{\oldding{#2}}}% Scale \oldding via optional argument
```

this line works well

```
\ding[0.5]{111}
```

However when I use in list items it breaks the code and I get an error

```
\begin{itemize}[label=\ding[0.5]{111}]
...
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the TEX SE

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Always make a [mre].

Comment: sorry my badddd

Comment: I hope I didn't hurt the community hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your command in `{...}`  if you want to use it inside of an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,pifont}
\let\oldding\ding% Store old \ding in \oldding
\renewcommand{\ding}[2][1]{\scalebox{#1}{\oldding{#2}}}% Scale \oldding via optional argument

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\ding[0.5]{111}

\begin{itemize}[label={\ding[0.5]{111}}]
\item ttt
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```